# find out reason of "Updating failed" in Post-editor

Tags: javascript, errors, block-editor, post-editor

In some cases, if there is issue in code or whatever, and try to update the post in Gutenberg post-editor, you will get "Updating failed" error message:

[image]

Is there any way to debug/find out the reason (i.e. in console) what error happened there or what was the response from the erroneous page?

Comment: I know this as a result of a too strict security mod on Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could poke around in the Network tab.  Filter the requests by XHR.  You can view the headers and the Response from there.

[image]

I think I read somewhere that error reporting is something Gutenberg dev is planning on improving in the future.